# Wordpress | Apply function at specific times of the day

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this function to hide a woocommerce category based on category slug. See here:

```html
/* Exclude Category from Shop*/

add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );

function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {

  $new_terms = array();

  // if a product category and on the shop page
  if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {

      if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'suviche' ) ) ) {
        $new_terms[] = $term;
      }

    }

    $terms = $new_terms;
  }

  return $terms;
}
```

And I have this other code to Apply Rules If Time is within the frame marked ( 9am - 5pm )

```html
<?php
$hr = date("H"); //get the hour in terms of double digits
$min= date("i"); //get the minutes in terms of double digits
$t = ($hr*60)+$min; //convert the current time into minutes
$f = (60*9); //calculate 9:00AM in minutes
$s = (60*17); //calculate 5:00PM in minutes

if(($t>f || $t<s)) //if the current time is between 9:00am to 5:00pm then don't apply function
{
//DO NOTHIGN
}
else //otherwise show execute function
{
//EXECUTE FUNCTION
}
?>
```

What I want to do is to run the filter to hide the product category if is out of the time fram ( 9am - 5pm )

Any Ideas would be great!

So far I have this but nothing:

```html
/* Exclude Category from Shop*/

add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );

function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {

 $new_terms = array();
 $hr = date("H"); //get the hour in terms of double digits
 $min= date("i"); //get the minutes in terms of double digits
 $t = ($hr*60)+$min; //convert the current time into minutes
 $f = (60*9); //calculate 9:00AM in minutes
 $s = (60*17); //calculate 5:00PM in minutes

  // if a product category and on the shop page
  if ( ( $t>f || $t<s) && in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() ) {

    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {

      if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'suviche' ) ) ) {
        $new_terms[] = $term;
      }

    }

    $terms = $new_terms;
  }

  return $terms;
}
```

Thanks again to whoever might help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem is you're not getting 9am for the day. You are just getting 9am for 1970, January 1st. Also, I wouldn't suggest working with minutes. Work with seconds.

Whenever you work with time in PHP, know that it is often beneficial to use a unix timestamp. A unix timestamp is a running count of the number of seconds that have elapsed since 1st January, 1970.

A handy converter can be found [here](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)

Try this instead.

```
$curTime    = strtotime("now"); //get the current time
$finishTime = strtotime('9am '.date('d-m-Y')); //calculate 9:00AM in seconds
$startTime  = strtotime('5pm '.date('d-m-Y')); //calculate 5:00PM in seconds

if(!($curTime > $startTime && $curTime < $finishTime)){
    //If we get into here then we're outside of the time range.
}
```

What we're doing here is using `strtotime("now")` to get the current time, and `date()` to get todays date, which is being concatenated with the time you want(9am and 5am). We're then using strtotime, to convert the whole thing into a unix timestamp. Which you can then compare later to see if the current time is greater or lesser than.

Also, these variables need `$` in front of them.

```
( $t>$f || $t<$s )
```

Hope this helps.